# Excluir string até chegar no caractere e ":"

Tags: c#, string

Como fazer para deletar uma parte da string até chegar no caractere ":".
Consegui fazer apagar depois ":", usando o código abaixo:

Exemplo String: uma_frase_aleatória: Ronison

```
string url = empresaweb2;
string resultado = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf(':'));
txbEmpresa.Text = resultado;
```

Resultado: uma_frase_aleatória

Sendo que o resultado que eu desejo é apenas o nome: Ronison

Lembrando que eu não sei o tamanho da frase antes do nome.

Comment: Tente isto... `url.Substring(url.IndexOf(':'), url.Length - 1);` Você inicia o substring a partir do ponto onde está : e vai até o final da string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Exemplo simples

Veja este exemplo para melhor entendimento do código

```
string url = "uma_frase_aleatória: Ronison";
string resultado = url.Split(':')[url.Split(':').Length - 1];
Console.Write(resultado);
```

[Executar](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TRWfWs)

O método `Split` divide a `string` em um `array`, a divisão é feita utilizando o `char` ':', então em cada ocorrência do ':' e criado uma nova `string` ou seja a `string` "uma_frase_aleatória: Ronison" se torna no `array`

```
[ "uma_frase_aleatória", " Ronison" ]
```

E então pegamos o ultimo índice no `array` que é

```
" Ronison"
```

## Com o seu código

Agora aplicando a mesma ideia mas no seu código

```
string url = empresaweb2;
string resultado = url.Split(':')[url.Split(':').Length - 1];
txbEmpresa.Text = resultado;
```

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Consegui fazer seguindo o método do @Wictor Chaves. Abraço!

Answer (score 6):

No seu código não tem porque você remover nada, e nem é possível em C# padrão. Você pega uma outra parte do código.

Você pode pegar da posição atual até o fim. Mas não se esqueça de verificar se achou o caractere que está buscando, caso contrário dará erro e sua aplicação quebrará.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var url = "http://abc.com";
        var posicao = url.IndexOf(':');
        if (posicao < 0) return; //aqui você trata como quiser se não achar a string
        WriteLine(url.Substring(posicao));
        WriteLine(url[posicao..]); //só para C# 8
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YOSZEG). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xWPdEM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/Substring.cs).

Na segunda linha sendo impressa estou usando C# 8 que tem a vantagem de ser mais rápido e não fazer alocação.

No seu código:

```
var posicao = empresaweb2.IndexOf(':');
if (posicao < 0) return; //aqui você trata como quiser se não achar a string
txbEmpresa.Text = empresaweb2.Substring(posicao);
```